# How to disconnect twilio client using the JS API?

Tags: javascript, api, twilio

The `twilio` API documentation mentions how to register the client (using the setup method) but there's no mention of how to unregister.

It appears that the `API` does expose a `Twilio.Device.destroy()` method, but I cannot find any official mention of it.

Is `destroy()` what I Am looking for?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/connection <- check that out

It seems the setup() method has been deprecated

Comment: @AniruddhAgarwal It most certainly has not https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/device. We're talking about `Twilio.Device` not `Twilio.Connection`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you were on the right track with `.destroy()`. We just added it to our documentation: https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/device#destroy

> **.destroy()**
>
> Destroys the device. Terminates active and pending connections. This
>   will trigger the offline event handler. Device will not be able to
>   make or receive new connections until you call Twilio.Device.setup()
>   again.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/connection

```
Twilio.Device.disconect()
```

Comment: `Twilio.Device.disconnect( handler(connection) )` registers a callback handler for disconnected connections. The `disconnect()` method operates on `Twilio.Connection` objects and ends a current connection. It does not actually unregister/disconnect a client.